# python3 canvasのobjectsに存在する範囲内でscrollbarを操作させたい

Tags: python3

はじめまして。
python3.6を使用して、GUIを作成しています。
Canvasに配置されるobjectsの範囲内で、scrollbarを操作させたいと考えていますが、方法が分かりません。
以下のコードは、scrollbarにバインドした、canvas_x、canvas_yにおいて、何等か記述すれば細かく制御できるかと思うのです。info関数は、canvasが現在どの範囲のcanvas内座標を表示しているか確認するためのものです。
bboxメソッドで現在のobjectsの座標範囲が取得できるため、これを利用しようと思うのですが、scrollbarへの移動範囲設定やノブの表示方法が分かりません。
どなたか実装方法をご存じないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Tkinter 8.5 referenceを確認したところ、canvasウィジット作成時に、scrollregionオプションを入れることで、スクロール範囲が設定できることが分かりました。
ウィジット作成後に、このscrollregionオプションの変更の仕方をご存知であれば、ご教示をお願いいたします。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_w = 800
        self.screen_h = 600
        self.dlg_pos_x = 100
        self.dlg_pos_y = 100

        return super().__init__()

    def createMainWindow(self):

        obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        return obj

    def btn_area(self, parent):
        _if_bt_w = int(self.screen_w)
        _if_bt_h = int(self.screen_h)

        self._InFrame_ = ttk.Frame(
            parent,
            width = _if_bt_w,
            height = _if_bt_h
            )

        self._Canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self._InFrame_,
            background = 'beige',
            scrollregion=(-1000, -500, 1200, 800)
            )

        self.canvas = self._Canvas


        self._InFrame_.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.E+tk.W)
        self._Canvas.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)


        self._InFrame_.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 760)
        self._InFrame_.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 560)


        self.canvas_v_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self._InFrame_,
            orient = tk.VERTICAL,
            command = self.canvas_y
            )

        self.canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.canvas_v_scroll.set

        self.canvas_h_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self._InFrame_,
            orient = tk.HORIZONTAL,
            command = self.canvas_x
            )

        self.canvas['xscrollcommand'] = self.canvas_h_scroll.set

        self.canvas_v_scroll.grid(row = 0,column = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
        self.canvas_h_scroll.grid(row = 1,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)

        self.maker1 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,100,300,200,fill='blue',tags = 'r1')
        self.maker2 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(-100,-100,100,100,fill='green',tags = 'r2')
        self.maker3 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(400,400,250,250,fill='yellow',tags = 'r3')


        return

    def canvas_x(self,*args, **kwargs):

        for a in args:
            print(a)

        for b in kwargs:
            print(b)

        self.canvas.xview(*args, **kwargs)
        self.info()

        return

    def canvas_y(self,*args, **kwargs):

        for a in args:
            print(a)

        for b in kwargs:
            print(b)

        self.canvas.yview(*args, **kwargs)
        self.info()

        return

    def info(self):
        x = self.canvas.winfo_x()
        y = self.canvas.winfo_y()
        w = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        h = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        print(x,y,w,h)

        cx1 = self.canvas.canvasx(x)
        cy1 = self.canvas.canvasy(y)
        cx2 = self.canvas.canvasx(x+w)
        cy2 = self.canvas.canvasy(y+h)

        print(cx1,cy1,cx2,cy2)
        self.canvas.bbox("all")
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    MainFrame = ttk.Frame(
        MainWindow_obj,
        class_ = 'MainApplication',
        borderwidth = 0
        )

    screen_obj.btn_area(MainWindow_obj)

    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません。自己解決してしまいました。

w.configureあるいはw[option]にて、scrollregionオプションを指定すればよいことがわかりました。
なお、ウィジットの座標系は、mainloop()実行後に正常な値となるため、本ソースコードでは、スクロールバーが押されたらオプションを変更しております。実用上では、.afterでメソッドを呼び出して、mainloop()実行後にオプションを変更します。
また、動的にscrollregionオプションを変更する場合、ウィジットサイズがscrollregionオプションのサイズの関係および現在の表示座標エリアの整合性を取る工夫が必要のようです。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class CreateScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_w = 800
        self.screen_h = 600
        self.dlg_pos_x = 100
        self.dlg_pos_y = 100

        return super().__init__()

    def createMainWindow(self):

        obj = ttk.tkinter.Tk() 

        geo_string = str(self.screen_w) + "x" + str(self.screen_h) + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_x)  + "+" + str(self.dlg_pos_y) 

        obj.geometry(geo_string) 

        return obj

    def btn_area(self, parent):
        _if_bt_w = int(self.screen_w)
        _if_bt_h = int(self.screen_h)

        self._InFrame_ = ttk.Frame(
            parent,
            width = _if_bt_w,
            height = _if_bt_h
            )

        self._Canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self._InFrame_,
            background = 'beige'
            )

        self.canvas = self._Canvas


        self._InFrame_.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.E+tk.W)
        self._Canvas.grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)


        self._InFrame_.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 760)
        self._InFrame_.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 560)


        self.canvas_v_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self._InFrame_,
            orient = tk.VERTICAL,
            command = self.canvas_y
            )

        self.canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.canvas_v_scroll.set

        self.canvas_h_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self._InFrame_,
            orient = tk.HORIZONTAL,
            command = self.canvas_x
            )

        self.canvas['xscrollcommand'] = self.canvas_h_scroll.set

        self.canvas_v_scroll.grid(row = 0,column = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)
        self.canvas_h_scroll.grid(row = 1,column = 0, sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)

        self.maker1 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(200,100,300,200,fill='blue',tags = 'r1')
        self.maker2 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(-100,-100,100,100,fill='green',tags = 'r2')
        self.maker3 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(600,400,850,650,fill='yellow',tags = 'r3')


        return

    def canvas_x(self,*args, **kwargs):

        self.canvas.xview(*args, **kwargs)

        self.range = self.canvas.bbox("all")
        w = self._Canvas.winfo_width()
        h = self._Canvas.winfo_height()

        dx0 = self.range[0]
        dy0 = self.range[1]
        dx1 = self.range[2]
        dy1 = self.range[3]

        dw = dx1-dx0
        dh = dy1-dy0

        if dw < w:
            dx1 += w-dw

        if dh < h:
            dy1 += h-dh


        self._Canvas['scrollregion'] = (dx0,dy0,dx1,dy1)

        return

    def canvas_y(self,*args, **kwargs):

        self.canvas.yview(*args, **kwargs)

        self.range = self.canvas.bbox("all")
        w = self._Canvas.winfo_width()
        h = self._Canvas.winfo_height()

        dx0 = self.range[0]
        dy0 = self.range[1]
        dx1 = self.range[2]
        dy1 = self.range[3]

        dw = dx1-dx0
        dh = dy1-dy0

        if dw < w:
            dx1 += w-dw

        if dh < h:
            dy1 += h-dh


        self._Canvas['scrollregion'] = (dx0,dy0,dx1,dy1)

        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_obj = CreateScreen()

    MainWindow_obj = screen_obj.createMainWindow()

    MainFrame = ttk.Frame(
        MainWindow_obj,
        class_ = 'MainApplication',
        borderwidth = 0
        )

    screen_obj.btn_area(MainWindow_obj)

    MainWindow_obj.mainloop()
```